# icons,images & javascript files missing from frontend after applying update command in magento 2.4.1?

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I've installed the magento v2.4.1 by downloading and uploading the zip file content and apply simple commands to install the magento.

I'm new to magento and don't understand much, So please read through the below and I've tried my best to explain the issue.

Use the below command to install magento:

```
php magento setup:install
```

I got the following message:

```
[Progress: 1347 / 1347]
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin_1d6ja1
```

After installation, I've found images,icon and javascript files went missing.

So I tried to look at this guide but wasn't able to understand that what I've to do here?
[stylesheet&images missing Magento guide](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032994352?_ga=2.87977243.2020210441.1611532313-1816124573.1611194406)

so I found a way from here [Magento Stackexchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder) to get back my missing stylesheet files & this solution works well.

Now, the problem is whenever I try to apply below commands to magento then I'll start missing of images, stylesheets and JS.

```
php magento setup:upgrade
```

So what I want is to get permanent fix of this issue and don't want to apply the missing stylesheet patch up commands to fix every time, I apply update or upgrade command.

To get back all the images and javsacript or theme related files I have to always apply commands in below manner once I upgrade or compile my code:

```
php magento setup di:compile
php magento setup:upgrade
php magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php magento cache:flush
php magento indexer:reindex
```

If I don't apply some of the above commands my theme seems broken.:( So how to fix this issue that my theme won't break after applying compile or upgrade commands???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in production mode, and are running setup:upgrade and you don't want regenerate static content because there is no need to, then you can use the following:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
```

--keep-generated is an optional argument that does not update static view files. It should be used only in production mode. It should not be used in developer mode.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-db-upgr.html#instgde-cli-db-upgr

Comment: Thanks that's working fine. Thank you so much for sharing knowledge. However, what if I run the command magento setup:di:compile so is in this case my assets files will regenerated. Am I right @tkashro?

Comment: @Jimil setup:di:compile does not affect the static assets, so it is not necessary to redeploy static content unless you run setup:upgrade first. Running setup:upgrade cleans various folders in the filesystem which you can observe in the commands output.

Comment: Hi, I run below commands 1st magento setup:di:compile and then magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated and 3rd command was magento cache:flush However, I've found that this cause the trouble with admin section as admin section now don't have any images. please check my post to see the output. @tkashro

Comment: Please try run setup:upgrade before setup:di:compile.